# Starting Jboss EAP and the UnknownHostException on the DHCP server Linux

Tags: linux, jboss, dhcp

I'm trying to start JBoss [EAP] 4.3.0.GA_CP06 but got the error Unknown Host Exception as below log.
I've suggested to map the IP and Hostname into etc/hosts file but the Admin said that this is DHCP, so it's no need to map as my suggestion.
It's sound correctly, right?
Any suggest to get over this error?

### Appreciate any input.

Update:

## Using dig command and the result return the correct IP.

> JBoss Bootstrap Environment
>
> JBOSS_HOME: /disk01/home/dmadmin/jboss-eap-4.3-src/jboss-as
>
> JAVA: /disk01/home/dmadmin/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java
>
> JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
>   -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>
> CLASSPATH:
>   /disk01/home/dmadmin/jboss-eap-4.3-src/jboss-as/bin/run.jar:/disk01/home/dmadmin/java/jdk1.6.0_45/lib/tools.jar
>
> =========================================================================
>
> 22:05:39,067 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...
>   22:05:39,083 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [EAP] 4.3.0.GA_CP06
>   (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_4_3_0_GA_CP06 date=201511180117) 22:05:39,084
>   INFO  [Server] Home Dir:
>   /disk01/home/dmadmin/jboss-eap-4.3-src/jboss-as 22:05:39,085 INFO 
>   [Server] Home URL:
>   file:/disk01/home/dmadmin/jboss-eap-4.3-src/jboss-as/ 22:05:39,085
>   INFO  [Server] Patch URL: null 22:05:39,085 INFO  [Server] Server
>   Name: default 22:05:39,086 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir:
>   /disk01/home/dmadmin/jboss-eap-4.3-src/jboss-as/server/default
>   22:05:39,086 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL:
>   file:/disk01/home/dmadmin/jboss-eap-4.3-src/jboss-as/server/default/
>   22:05:39,086 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir:
>   /disk01/home/dmadmin/jboss-eap-4.3-src/jboss-as/server/default/log
>   22:05:39,086 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir:
>   /disk01/home/dmadmin/jboss-eap-4.3-src/jboss-as/server/default/tmp
>   22:05:39,087 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename:
>   jboss-service.xml 22:05:40,180 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version:
>   1.6.0_45,Sun Microsystems Inc. 22:05:40,181 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.45-b01,Sun Microsystems Inc.
>   22:05:40,181 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Linux
>   2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64,amd64 22:05:40,307 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/disk01/home/dmadmin/jboss-eap-4.3-src/jboss-as/lib/endorsed
>   22:05:40,829 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized 22:05:44,187 WARN 
>   [BasicMBeanRegistry] javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException:
>   preRegister() failed:
>   [ObjectName='jboss.remoting:service=NetworkRegistry',
>   Class=org.jboss.remoting.network.NetworkRegistry
>   (org.jboss.remoting.network.NetworkRegistry@2ea45536)] 22:05:44,207
>   ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not create deployment:
>   file:/disk01/home/dmadmin/jboss-eap-4.3-src/jboss-as/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml
>   org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: - nested throwable:
>   (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:196)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:226)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>     at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.install(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.create(SARDeployer.java:249)     at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:969)   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:818)   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)    at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)    at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>     at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)   at
>   org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)     at
>   org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)    at
>   org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:513)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1451)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1350)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.createMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:345)
>     at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:157)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.internalInstall(ServiceConfigurator.java:455)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:171)
>     ... 36 more Caused by: javax.management.MBeanException  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.handleInvocationExceptions(ReflectedDispatcher.java:180)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:163)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)    at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)    at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl$3.run(MBeanServerImpl.java:1422)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1417)
>     ... 41 more Caused by: javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException:
>   preRegister() failed:
>   [ObjectName='jboss.remoting:service=NetworkRegistry',
>   Class=org.jboss.remoting.network.NetworkRegistry
>   (org.jboss.remoting.network.NetworkRegistry@2ea45536)]    at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.invokePreRegister(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:713)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.registerMBean(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:211)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>     ... 51 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception creating
>   identity: java.net.UnknownHostException: ADDSOME.CGV.com:
>   ADDSOME.CGV.com   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1402)  at
>   org.jboss.remoting.ident.Identity.get(Identity.java:205)  at
>   org.jboss.remoting.network.NetworkRegistry.preRegister(NetworkRegistry.java:268)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invokePreRegister(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:966)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.modelmbean.ModelMBeanInvoker.invokePreRegister(ModelMBeanInvoker.java:489)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.preRegister(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:654)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.invokePreRegister(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:697)
>     ... 56 more Failed to boot JBoss:
>   org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: - nested throwable:
>   (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:196)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:226)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>     at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.install(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.create(SARDeployer.java:249)     at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:969)   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:818)   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)   at
>   org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)    at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)    at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>     at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)   at
>   org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)     at
>   org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)    at
>   org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:513)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1451)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1350)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.createMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:345)
>     at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:157)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.internalInstall(ServiceConfigurator.java:455)
>     at
>   org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:171)
>     ... 36 more Caused by: javax.management.MBeanException  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.handleInvocationExceptions(ReflectedDispatcher.java:180)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:163)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)  at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)    at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
>     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)    at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl$3.run(MBeanServerImpl.java:1422)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:1417)
>     ... 41 more Caused by: javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException:
>   preRegister() failed:
>   [ObjectName='jboss.remoting:service=NetworkRegistry',
>   Class=org.jboss.remoting.network.NetworkRegistry
>   (org.jboss.remoting.network.NetworkRegistry@2ea45536)]    at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.invokePreRegister(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:713)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.registerMBean(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:211)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
>     ... 51 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception creating
>   identity: java.net.UnknownHostException: ADDSOME.CGV.com:
>   ADDSOME.CGV.com   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1402)  at
>   org.jboss.remoting.ident.Identity.get(Identity.java:205)  at
>   org.jboss.remoting.network.NetworkRegistry.preRegister(NetworkRegistry.java:268)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invokePreRegister(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:966)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.modelmbean.ModelMBeanInvoker.invokePreRegister(ModelMBeanInvoker.java:489)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.preRegister(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:654)
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.invokePreRegister(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:697)
>     ... 56 more 22:05:44,216 INFO  [Server] Runtime shutdown hook called,
>   forceHalt: true 22:05:44,226 INFO  [Server] JBoss SHUTDOWN:
>   Undeploying all packages 22:05:44,265 INFO  [Server] Shutdown complete
>   Shutdown complete Halting VM

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stack, I see

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception creating identity: java.net.UnknownHostException: ADDSOME.CGV.com: ADDSOME.CGV.com at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1402)

Have you tried pinging `ADDSOME.CGV.com`? There is an attempt to get the localhost, but I don't see `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. I'd figure that this isn't resolving properly.

> Caused by: javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException: preRegister() failed: [ObjectName='jboss.remoting:service=NetworkRegistry', Class=org.jboss.remoting.network.NetworkRegistry

This is being thrown higher, so it's probably being caused by the identity exception, but I wanted to help narrow the scope of your search to the connective tissue around `preRegister()`, which is being called by `org.jboss.remoting.network.NetworkRegistry`

Comment: I'm able to ping this ADDSOME.CGV.com sucessfully. As my latest test, the dig command return the correct IP. So the server name is working correctly. Do we have to register any port in the service file?

Comment: Good point. https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/Admin_Console_Guide/en-US/html/Administration_Console_User_Guide-Port_Configuration.html shows the default port configurations. Normally, anything localhost would be on port 8080 in order to keep port 80 clear for regular web traffic, unless you want to setup a listener on port 80.

Comment: I just let it as default so there's no need to add the port 8080 in the service file(It's existed there already). I'm still on my debugging. Any suggestion is appreciate.